# How to migrate from ModelMapper to MapStruct?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am currently using ModelMapper. From my perspective that's quite user friendly. However, I need to migrate to MapStruct because of performance issues. Imagine that I have `Tariff` class as below

```java
@Setter @Getter @Builder @ToString
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "tariff")
public class Tariff {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_energy_mix")
    private EnergyMix energyMix;
```

And My `TariffDTO` as below

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class TariffDTO {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("id_energy_mix")
    @SerializedName("id_energy_mix")
    private EnergyMixDTO energyMix;
```

When I need to convert Tariff to TariffDTO, I am using ModelMapper as below

```java
    public TariffDTO mapperTariffToDTO(Tariff tariff) {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        TypeMap<Tariff, TariffDTO> typeMap = modelMapper.createTypeMap(Tariff.class, TariffDTO.class);

        if (tariff.getEnergyMix() != null) {
            typeMap.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.<EnergyMixDTO>map(src -> mapperEnergyMixToDTO(tariff.getEnergyMix()),
                    (dest, v) -> dest.setEnergyMix(v)));
        }
        return modelMapper.map(tariff, TariffDTO.class);

    public EnergyMixDTO mapperEnergyMixToDTO(EnergyMix energyMix) {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        return modelMapper.map(energyMix, EnergyMixDTO.class);
    }
```

These code blocks gives me expected output. I didn't need to inclued mapping for `id` in ModelMapper.

When I tried with MapStruct, I needed create an interface and add mapping for each single property as below

```java
    @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id")
    // I want to add EnergyMix to EnergyMixDTO too
    TariffDTO mapperTariffToDTO(Tariff tariff);
```

My first question, is there a way to avoid boilerplate code in MapStruct? I mean if I can avoid to adding mappings for the same attribute names. On the other hand, I need to create a mapper for `EnergyMix` to `EnergyMixDTO` and I might need to use that in different classes in my project. Therefore, I want to create another class for `EnergyMix` to `EnergyMixDTO` mapper and use that inside `Tariff` to `TariffDTO` mapper. Is that possible?

Comment: Just a note, `ModelMapper` should be a single instance across your application, no need to instantiate manually everywhere it's used. Since you are using spring, it should be a bean.

Comment: @Chaosfire could you manipulate my example and show me how to do with bean, please?

Comment: Declare it with a bean method and configure it there - 
`@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    //configure, add type maps, convertes, etc.
    return mapper;
 }` A guide - [ModelMapper as spring bean](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application).

Comment: `I needed create an interface and add mapping for each single property as below`. Identically named properties are copied automatically. You need to declare mappings only when properties have different names

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I have wrote unit test for that but all properties were coming `null`

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you need 2 mappers:

EnergyMixMapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING, injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public interface EnergyMixMapper {

    EnergyMixDto toDto(EnergyMix entity);

}
```

TariffMapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING, 
        injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR, 
        uses = { EnergyMixMapper.class })
public interface TariffMapper {

    TariffDto toDto(Tariff entity);

}
```

On the TariffMapper you need to specify to use another mapper: `uses = { EnergyMixMapper.class }` Mapstract is able then to determine that for converting EnergyMix into EnergyMixDto can use that mapper.

That's all you need! As you can see, really simple without boilerplate code if the entity and dto have the same fields name.

The implementation of the two mappers will be:

EnergyMixMapperImpl:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2024-02-01T18:48:14+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: Eclipse JDT (IDE) 3.36.0.v20231114-0937, environment: Java 17.0.5 (Eclipse Adoptium)"
)
@Component
public class EnergyMixMapperImpl implements EnergyMixMapper {

    @Override
    public EnergyMixDto toDto(EnergyMix entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        EnergyMixDto.EnergyMixDtoBuilder<?, ?> energyMixDto = EnergyMixDto.builder();

        energyMixDto.fieldA( entity.getFieldA() );
        energyMixDto.fieldB( entity.getFieldB() );
        energyMixDto.id( entity.getId() );

        return energyMixDto.build();
    }
}
```

TariffMapperImpl:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2024-02-01T18:48:14+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: Eclipse JDT (IDE) 3.36.0.v20231114-0937, environment: Java 17.0.5 (Eclipse Adoptium)"
)
@Component
public class TariffMapperImpl implements TariffMapper {

    private final EnergyMixMapper energyMixMapper;

    @Autowired
    public TariffMapperImpl(EnergyMixMapper energyMixMapper) {

        this.energyMixMapper = energyMixMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public TariffDto toDto(Tariff entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        TariffDto.TariffDtoBuilder<?, ?> tariffDto = TariffDto.builder();

        tariffDto.energyMix( energyMixMapper.toDto( entity.getEnergyMix() ) );
        tariffDto.id( entity.getId() );

        return tariffDto.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do more with MapStruct if you need, just read the reference guide: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/